# Codeigniter Image Resize giving wrong output

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-resizing

I am using **Codeigniter 2.0.2** 
  I want image Dimension **60x70** This Code not giving any error and generating image which 
*width = 60 and height = 44*
What is problem ?

```
        $config['source_image'] = $preview_path;
        $config['new_image'] = $dir_small_prev.$file_namee;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['master_dim'] = 'width';
        $config['width'] = 60;
        $config['height'] = 70;
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['quality'] = 100;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize()){
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
```

Comment: If you want to maintain the quality of the original image, you'll have to crop the image first (to fit your desired wXh ratio), and then resize it to your desired size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;` Set this to `FALSE`

You'll skew your image, but you'll get the dimensions you're looking for

Comment: 1 more thing i want to know codeigniter generating animated preview for gif file ?